# How to do the command "set serveroutput on"

Tags: php, oracle, sqlplus

How to do the command "set serveroutput on" in oracle(or mysql) by php? It's necessary to see the output of the procedure by php

Comment: Maybe you should add some reference about that command. Into what has such a command to be entered for example?

Comment: To implement sqlplus's serveroutput functionality one would use the following procedures of the dbms_output package: `disable`, `enable`, `get_line`, `get_lines`. However, for error conditions: 1) do not use `when others then dbms_output...` just let the errors bubble back to your php. 2) To throw application errors use `raise_application_error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use SET SERVEROUTPUT ON - that is an SQLPLUS command (not an SQL statement).

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON can't be used in PHP or any other language as an SQL statement - it is just a command that is interpreted the SQLPLUS program.  (Other programs may interpret this command also, but that is for the purpose of being compatible with SQLPLUS.)

Use something like this instead:
(Assuming `$db` is your PHP database connection handle):

```
$sql = <<ADD YOUR SQL STATEMENT HERE>>;

if ($db->Execute($sql) === false) {
    echo "<B>ERROR:</B> An error occurred";
    echo "MESSAGE: " . $db->ErrorMsg()  . "<BR>";

}
else {
    //Successful
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with my code:<pre>$sql = "exec insert_lloguer(".$_POST['client'].",  ".$_POST['vehicle'].", ".$_POST['venedor'].", '".$_POST['datai']."', ".$_POST['kmi'].")";

if ($conn->Execute($sql) === false) {
echo "<B>ERROR:</B> An error occurred";
echo "MESSAGE: " . $conn>ErrorMsg()  . "<BR>";

}
else {
 echo "<p>The lloguer is added to the database correctly</p>";
}<code>

Comment: no one error. the problem is that I don't receive the error. I need to print the error that I receive on sqlplus executing my procedure insert_lloguer(...)

Comment: @Giuseppe are you saying you throw errors by way of dbms_output and not raising the exception? if so that is really poor form. to replicate sql*plus in terms of serverout, you need to poll dbms_output.get_lines and process the returned array of lines (which is what sqlplus does in the background).

Comment: That is right - if you are raising an SQL exception, it should propagate through to the above listed PHP code.    If, on the other hand you need to log or record a non fatal error, can you log the error in a "LOG" table in ORACLE?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the output of the sql script I suggest you launch a shell that execute sqlplus.
You can export the sqlplus log to a text file and after read the text file.